# TinyMCE editor content margin

Tags: css, editor, tinymce, margin

I have a problem on several browsers except for FF.
I have a p element with the default text and I transform this element into a tinyMCE editor. 
The problem is that the content isn't displayed at the top of the editor and I didn't found a solution.

Here is a screenshot of the problem :

http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=120626123025897245.png

The right part is the default content which is not at the top.
The left part is when I remove the content on focus and start typing something. It gets back at the top.

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle to show the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have this issue but it not due to tinyMCE. 
I removed some style myself in javascript.